# Writing trigger in MySQL regarding two tables, with logic

Tags: mysql, triggers, logic

When I write trigger mentioned below I get error "INSERT not expected here"

Tables movies, Lightning is many to many relation with associative table.

My aim is to get Lumens_power in 'Lightning' table set as 5300 when Movies table 'genre' attribute is equal to 'action' .

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `Film_industry`.`Movies_AFTER_INSERT` 
AFTER INSERT ON `Movies` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT genre,
        CASE WHEN genre = 'action' THEN INSERT INTO Lightning(id, type, Lumens_power) values('NEW.Movies_id', 'directed', '5300');
        END;
    FROM Movies;
END;
```

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Film_industry`.`Movies`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Film_industry`.`Movies` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `released_on` DATE NOT NULL,
  `genre` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  `rating` DECIMAL(2,1) NOT NULL,
  `finansial_stake` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `Supporting_object_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `title_UNIQUE` (`title` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_Movies_Supporting_object1_idx` (`Supporting_object_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Movies_Supporting_object1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Supporting_object_id`)
    REFERENCES `Film_industry`.`Supporting_object` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Film_industry`.`Lightning`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Film_industry`.`Lightning` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Lumens_power` INT NOT NULL,
  `Scene_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_Lightning_Scene1_idx` (`Scene_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Lightning_Scene1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Scene_id`)
    REFERENCES `Film_industry`.`Scene` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value for the `genre` column simply using

```
IF (NEW.genre = 'action') then
  INSERT...
END;
```

Note that the `Lightning`-table also contains `Scene_id` which references the `Film_industry.Scene.id`. It is defined as `NOT NULL`, so you need to come up with the logic to set it appropriately.

Comment: So can you give me an idea how to implement logic for foreign key?I wrote this but still not working.. CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `Film_industry`.`Movies_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `Movies` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.genre = 'action') THEN INSERT INTO Lightning(Lightning_id, type, Lumens_power) values(NEW.id, 'directed', '5300');
     END IF;
END;

Comment: There is really no information provided for that. The `Scene_id` is set to be `NOT NULL` in the `Lightning`-table, so you will need a value for that before inserting a row to that table. The `Movies` table does not have that information. You should determine what determines the appropriate `Scene_id` for a new movie? If there is no specific one, choose one of the values from the `Scene`-table and use that ID as a constant in the insert.